# How to cast a value retrieved from text field to int in java?

Tags: java

How to cast a value retrieved from text field to `int` in Java?

This retrieves a value from `JTextField` named `BarcodeTxt`:

```
String barcode = BarcodeTxt.getText();
```

I want the value in the form of `int` rather than `String`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parseInt()` method, from the Integer class, to do that.

```
// use camelCase to name variables and do not start 
// a variable name with uppercased letter - leave that
// for classes
String barCode = BarcodeTxt.getText();
int converted = Integer.parseInt(barCode);
```

As a reference, check the [Javadoc for `Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Please don't answer obviously duplicate questions. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) thread on how to handle these.

Comment: Didn't know about that -- sorry.